# Trying to create a DAO recordset from an array

Tags: vb6, dao

I'm using VB6 and trying to create a DAO recordset from an array of data.
I want something like this but I've hit all kinds of problems

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim tdf As New DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As New DAO.Field

rst.Fields.Append tdf.CreateField(arrayHeader(0), adInteger, 5)
rst.OpenRecordset

rst.AddNew Array(arrayHeader(0), arrayHeader(1)), Array (arrData(0), arrData(1))
```

Code is simplified to highlight the problem I have.
Arrays are declared and have data in them. Problem at the moment is trying to add the field to the recordset. Is it possible to have a disconnected DAO RecordSet like this?
I have to use DAO for various reasons that really aren't worth getting into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to fabricate a DAO Recordset in that way. A DAO Recordset cannot be disconnected; it needs to be always connected to a data source.

For what it's worth, a disconnected ADODB Recordset can be fabricated in almost exactly the way you have coded.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did know ADO RecordSets would work. Guess I'll have to write the data back to a db before I can use it.